# Which Python Bayesian text classification modules are similar to dbacl?

Tags: python, text, classification, bayesian

A quick Google search reveals that there are a good number of Bayesian classifiers implemented as Python modules. If I want wrapped, high-level functionality similar to [dbacl](http://dbacl.sourceforge.net/), which of those modules is right for me?

Training

```
% dbacl -l one sample1.txt
% dbacl -l two sample2.txt
```

Classification

```
% dbacl -c one -c two sample3.txt -v
one
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you'll find the [nltk](http://www.nltk.org) helpful.  Specifically, the [classify module](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.classify-module.html).

Comment: I don't believe NLTK includes a feature selection algorithm, but it has frequency dist tools etc so you can write your own and feed it to the classifier of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to detect language
[this](http://cogscicoder.blogspot.com/2009/03/automatic-language-identification-using.html) works fine even with pretty short texts.

The api is pretty close to yours but
I don't know if it is called a Bayesian classifier.

Answer (score -1):

Try [Mallet](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu) and [LingPipe](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/). they provide more models for the classifier.

Comment: These are Java libraries, not Python.